# Is it possible to modify Request.ReferrerUrl using a URL argument?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get around an issue for a customer that have a site developed by a previous developer.  The following is the line of code causing the issue:

```
args.AddParam("REFERER","",Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

Therefore if you navigate directly to this page using the URL, it returns a null exception error.  I know that to fix this the code should first be checking if UrlReferrer is set to null, however I am trying to find a way around this problem without having to change any source.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no URL (Querystring) argument that can set the `REFERER` http header to something. The only way you can do it is to link to the page from another one, and only navigate to it in that way.

Comment: That doesn't work either, there's also a Redirect.aspx page and you can use it as Redirect.aspx?URL=http://myUrl.com and within the code for this there is a line that redirects you to the correct page i.e.

Response.Redirect(newUrl);

However this still throws the null exception when it tries to get the ReferrerUrl

Comment: moorcroft: That seems strange. Is a proxy clearing that field?

Comment: No it's not going through a proxy, I'm testing it on localhost

Comment: moorcraft: You may still have a proxy set up locally. I've just tested it here (VS2008, Framework 2.0) and it works. Something else is happening ...

Comment: Perhaps your `args` object is null. What is it?

Comment: Nope it's not null, because I have other arguments that add to it just fine

Comment: Well mate, I don't know what to tell you other than I cannot reproduce your problem. I suggest you start with a simple example, in a new project, that demonstrates the issue, and go from there.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, It's a VS .Net 2003 project (Framework 1.1, not VS 2008